# Efficient distance calculations for big meshgrid Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for help to speed up my code, the purpose of the code is to generate high res images from sensor data, based on the distance and angle between the sensor and the pixels in the picture. I have data from 100 sensors at more than 200 different positions of those sensors (they are moving around in the picture).
For my computer at this time it takes ~90seconds to do this for just 50 sensors at one positions - the 200 positions takes to long... 
Please give suggestions on how to improve this (also if I have taken a strange approach).

```
import numpy as np

xstart=-200
xstop=20
xstep=0.05
ystart=-1500
ystop=-1300
ystep=0.05

deg_limit = 10
rad_limit=np.radians(deg_limit)

Xrange=np.arange(xstart,xstop,xstep)
Yrange=np.arange(ystart,ystop,ystep)

sensor1=np.zeros((3))
sensor1[0]=-100
sensor1[1]=-1400
sensor1[2]=4
sensor2=sensor1.copy()+[1,0,0]
sensor3=sensor1.copy()+[0,1,0]
sensor4=sensor1.copy()+[2,0,0]
sensor5=sensor1.copy()+[0,2,0]
sensor6=sensor1.copy()+[3,0,0]
sensor7=sensor1.copy()+[0,3,0]
sensor8=sensor1.copy()+[0,4,0]
sensor9=sensor1.copy()+[4,0,0]
sensor10=sensor1.copy()+[0,5,0]

sensors=[sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5,sensor6,sensor7,sensor8,sensor9,sensor10]
vector=np.zeros((3))
image=np.zeros((len(Yrange),len(Xrange)))
distanceimage=image.copy()
angleimage=image.copy()
testvector=[1/2,1/3,-1/10]#np.cross((sensor2-sensor1),(sensor3-sensor1))

testvector=testvector/np.sqrt(testvector[0]**2+testvector[1]**2+testvector[2]**2)
for _ in range(0,5):
    #outer loop for reading the sensorpositions and sampled values
    #inner loop for looping through the sensprs
    for sensor in sensors:
        xdist=Xrange-sensor[0]
        ydist=(Yrange-sensor[1])
        zdist=0-sensor[2]
        #Here should be a requirement that checks for the angle from
        #the point to the pixel and only adds to the image if the angle
        #within a certain range

        distanceimage=np.sqrt((xdist*xdist)+(ydist*ydist)[:,np.newaxis]+zdist*zdist)

        angleimage=(np.arccos((testvector[0]*xdist+testvector[1]*ydist[:,np.newaxis])/(distanceimage)))
        image[np.abs(angleimage)<rad_limit]+=distanceimage[np.abs(angleimage)<rad_limit]
        #Here I would like to use this "imagedistance" in different algoritms, i.e. selecting
        #the sampled values from each sensor
```

Comment: Do you understand that your `xdist` and `ydist` are 2D arrays of a shape of 10000x10000? Was it your intention in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the input - it was my intention but without much thought behind it... So I changed it to decrease the number of calculations needed. So the code is updated..